# RxJava2 Is there is any method like flapMap to handle error

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-java2, clean-architecture

I'm using RxJava2 in my android app.

I want to know if there is any method like flapMap that I can use for handling errors.

So, What I want to know:

Is there any method that returns another observable when an error occurs?

Example of What I want

```
fun getSomething() : Flowable<Something> { //retrun type can be Single or Maybe
    return somethingDB.getData().`method that return new Observable onError` {
        return@`method that return new Observable onError` somethingServer.getData()
    }
}
```

What does `method that return new Observable onError` can be?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

```
 Flowable.just(1)
            .doOnError((e)->{
                //do something when error
            }).onErrorReturn((it)->{
        // return a value when error
        return 1;
    })
```

Is it your want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I don't want to call doOnError. I add some detail to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way:

```
fun getSomething() : Flowable<Something> { //retrun type can be Single or Maybe
     var data = somethingDB.getData() : List<Data>  // somethingDB.getData() return List, not return Observable
      if (data==null)
          return somethingDB.getData()
      else return data 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I found another way for me.